# Append one link to jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, append, jquery-ui-autocomplete

what i want to achieve is, that when the autcompletion list is rendered, an additional div with one link is appended to the resultlist. somehow this is not working for me. i've tried

```
    $(".ui-autocomplete").append('<div style="border:1px solid red"><a href="#">Click me to get in contact</a></div>');
```

but that's not working. If i do

```
    $(".ui-autocomplete").append('<p>Ramo</p>');
```

then i get a red border around the ul element of the autocomplete box.That's fine, so i thought a simple append should work.

Any ideas for that issue?

Best regards,
Ramo

Comment: One problem, maybe not your only one, but your A link code has a typo, missing second quotes after setting href attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
  $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        open: function(){
            $(".ui-autocomplete").append('<li style="border:1px solid red"><a href="#">Click me to get in contact</a></li>');
        }
    });
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/uuPGq/

Comment: Hi, thanks. but this appends a list element inside the resultbox, right? i would prefer having a link (in a div) outside of the resultbox. Is that possible to?

Comment: @ramo the problem is that the resultbox is a `<ul>` element and you must put things inside it, otherwise you get this http://jsfiddle.net/uuPGq/2/

Comment: wouldn't it be possible to wrap the <ul> element of the resultbox in a <div> with dynamich height and append to this <div> another <div> with an link in it?

Comment: @ramo it looks a little overcomplicated, you could style the last li differently, if you want it to stand out or to be deifferent from the others, but what you are proposing looks complex