# Append and persist additional element to jQuery ui-autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

What I want to achieve is that when a user searches for a result, the last result is always the option to "add new".

I also want to persist that option even after no more results are available. So when the auto-complete has no more results, it still shows the "add new" option. The option should only disappear after the field loses focus.

So far I can display the option, but am unable to keep it there after the available results have been exhausted. I don't know how to approach this part?

[Append one link to jquery ui autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879930/append-one-link-to-jquery-ui-autocomplete) and [Add additional link to jquery ui autocomplete list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598098/add-additional-link-to-jquery-ui-autocomplete-list) didn't help with the persisting part of the problem.

Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c01gat3/ufa70bza/

Cheers.

```
$(function() {

    var addnew = '<li class="ui-menu-item" id="addnew" onClick="alert(\'add new customer\')">Add New Customer</li>';

    var availableTagsCustomerCode = [
    "ABCE001",
    "ABCD010",
    "BCDE100",
    "CDEF002",
    "DEFG020",
    "EFGH200",
    ];

    $( "#customer-code" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTagsCustomerCode,

        'open': function(e, ui) {
                $(".ui-autocomplete").append(addnew);
            }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a message to say that no results where found. As you already added a callback for the "open" event, it will come naturally. See the fiddle below.

```
$(function() {

var addnew = '<li class="ui-menu-item" id="addnew" onClick="alert(\'add new customer\')">Add New Customer</li>';

var availableTagsCustomerCode = [
"ABCE001",
"ABCD010",
"BCDE100",
"CDEF002",
"DEFG020",
"EFGH200"
];

$( "#customer-code" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTagsCustomerCode,

    'open': function(e, ui) {
            $(".ui-autocomplete").append(addnew);
        },
    response: function(event, ui) {
        if (!ui.content.length) {
            var noResult = { value:"",label:"No results found" };
            ui.content.push(noResult);
        }
    }
});
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ufa70bza/2/

Comment: ooooh, I like that! Thanks :)